# Count function fitness in binary particle swarm optimisation [BPSO]

Tags: particle-swarm

I have BPSO with [function1](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S1002007108002189-si14.gif) and dont know how to count value. I know how to update velocity. And know values of vector x. x[i] = 0 or 1.
Thanks

I want to optimize function1. Single particle contains vectors: velocity[-Vmax,Vmax] and x[0 or 1]. First I initialize my particles with random numbers. Then I update velocities. Next step update x. Last step is to count function value and this is main problem. I don't know which values should I use to do this.

Comment: Can you provide relevant information on what you have tried, where the problem is, and what you are expecting?

Comment: I want to optimize function1. Single particle contains vectors: velocity[-Vmax,Vmax] and x[0 or 1]. First I initialize my particles with random numbers. Then I update velocities. Next step update x. Last step is to count function value and this is main problem. I don't know which values should I use to do this. Thx